# Grails: data from Ajax call not shown in params variable in Controller

Tags: ajax, grails

I have to make an ajax call to deliever some data. The strange thing is that the data apperently will not be transmitted to the action in the controller:

this is my ajax call:

```
var params = [id: "3", version: "58", selected: "true", format: "json"]

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "/selection/ajaxUpdate",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: params,
            success:function(data,textStatus){
                console.log("success: ",data)
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
                console.log("error: ",XMLHttpRequest)
            }
        });
```

this is my action in controller "selection":

```
@Transactional    
def ajaxUpdate(){

    println params
    .... other stuff ...
}
```

The println params command just outputs: "[controller:selection, format:null, action:ajaxUpdate]"

Because of the println the action is obviously called, but without the ajax params :(

Does anyone know a solution?

Thx in advance

Comment: Would you like it to be normal grails params if so https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuemail-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/views/queueMail/main.gsp#L233-L241 try something like this and replace your params above to var params = {id: "3", version: "58", selected: "true"}  and in the example from `data: $('#search').serialize(),` to `data: params,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vahid is right: what a dumb js mistake. Of course i need to setup the params as a json-object {} instead of an array []. So this one works:

```
{id: "3", version: "58", selected: "true", format: "json"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Grails action to accept JSON params

```
@Transactional    
def ajaxUpdate(){
    def jsonParams = request.JSON
    println jsonParams   // this will print the ajax params

    println params
    .... other stuff ...
}
```

Comment: wasnt needed :)